# Problem cache with django/Wsgi apache

Tags: django, apache, caching

I am working on apache with a Django project and i got some issues. When i modify a file, sometimes my modifications is not use by apache. I have to restart it to apply my modification.

How can i force to reload all file on every request?

Thank you

Comment: "How can i force to reload all file on every request?" - Run the built-in Django HTTP server (./manage.py runserver)! That's what it's for ;)

Comment: Yes, but i have to use apache :) But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

It explains everything about how/when code reloading works under Apache/mod_wsgi if that is what you are using.

Comment: Edit your original question and supply the mod_wsgi parts of your Apache configuration. You may have missed something. Plus will help if you actually explain what from that document you used along with what files you are modifying which you say changes aren't being picked up from. In other words, you have not supplied enough information for us to help you with why the solutions given don't work.

Comment: I used MaxRequestsPerChild 1, that's was I miss. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a development environment locally, you should use the built in HTTP server that the django package provides:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server

This will reload any changes. If you are running this dev server, you will need to also tell it to server your media files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

The dev server shouldn't be used to server live code, so when you launch your code on your production server, you will always need to use apache/nginx (and will have to restart the server anytime you want to see the changes)

Comment: And there is no way to force apache to reload file everytime? Because my local server is a debian with VMWare.

Comment: I believe my old boss (who was pretty hardcore) said that there was no way. I agree, it is really strange :/ As far as I can see, just using the built-in Django development server is actually a good solution in every way.

Answer (score 0):

Graham just got it:-)

You will need the `Daemon Mode` to tackle with your issues.

Do follow to read:

[Reloading Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode)